# Guide to installing Hardy Heron via USB drive on a laptop running Windows XP?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 8.04

I want to dual boot Windows XP and Hardy Heron. I have partitioned my single hard drive, created a boot-able pen drive with the Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS ISO, I am aware how to boot and start the installation but the newly made partition is not displayed when it reaches that stage. Someone please instruct me how to proceed.

Comment: Hardy Heron release is no longer supported , Ubuntu 12.04 is current release and recommended , why not try the newer one for better support.

Comment: Again, *why* are you trying to use such an old version? If the newer ones don't work, it is possible to get them to work. The old ones don't have fixed for various new hardware, they have older software, it is hard to get support for them, and they have more unpatched security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have noted, Hardy Heron 8.04 LTS is *no longer supported* for desktop use and will soon not be supported, period. Your problem sounds like its a newer hardware incompatibility with the very old Hardy.

Please consider using the latest Precise 12.04 LTS, or if you need a legacy release for some reason, try 10.04 LTS.